# Want to assign the value of a dummy variable at one time in R

Tags: r

I already have a variable, say *year*, which is generated by

```
year <- seq(from=1790,to=1970,by=10)
```

Now I want to generate a dummy variable, say *z*, which takes the value of 1 at points *year=1940* and *year=1950*, and 0 everywhere else. My method, which looks awkward for me, is

```
z <- rep(0,times=length(year))   # initialize z
z[year==1940|year==1950] <- 1
```

Now I am wondering if there is any better method, say assigning the value at one time, since the initializing of z is actually time consuming.

Comment: to initialise an integer/numeric vector, you should use `integer(length(year))` or `numeric(length(year))` than using `rep`.

Comment: what's the length of `year` vector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
z <- as.numeric(year %in% c(1940, 1950))
```

Although I'm curious; what you have should already be fast enough for all practical purposes.

Comment: I don't think the concern is about speed. It's about having to assign `z` first and then replace `0` with `1`.

Comment: @Arun OP did say "time consuming" which makes me wonder what he's doing. Some kind of Monte Carlo, I guess.

Comment: ah yes indeed. missed that. `rep` will be slower than say, `numeric(length(year))`

Comment: @HongOoi Thanks for your help. I am just doing some simulation work, and the actual time indicative vector can be much larger than _year_, so I think initializing _z_ will cost some time.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, using `|` seems to be a little faster, although this only makes sense if your vector is much larger:

```
> as.integer(year %in% c(1940, 1950))
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0

> as.integer(year==1940 | year==1950)
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
```

Microbenchmark results:

```
Unit: microseconds
                                    expr   min    lq median    uq     max neval
     as.integer(year %in% c(1940, 1950)) 4.004 4.733  5.097 5.461 103.752  1000
 as.integer(year == 1940 | year == 1950) 1.820 2.185  2.548 2.912   9.829  1000
```

Comment: Thanks, both of the method work fine. By the way, which function did you call to measure the time cost in the unit of microseconds? I only know `system.time()` but it does not return the results that you showed.